# Download older ipa file from ituneconnect

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight, ipa

I have uploaded new build for my app store app and published the same.
Now I want the previous version of ipa for some other purpose. How can I download the ipa ?

I can download the older builds in the android publish but i am unable to find the way to download the ipa from ituneconnect developer portal

Comment: did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Testflight` & use build number whatever you want & invite via email id's.